# com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance IllegalStateException: Node failed to start

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I am trying to a POC for auto-discovery of hazelcast instance in ec2. These ec2 instances would be in same security group, which should be able to find other nodes of hazelcast and together these will form a cluster of Hazelcast. When trying to spin-up a spring boot app on AWS instance, with profile to enable AWS config, it throws exception: Node failed to start!

Here is the code snippet:

```
@value("${spring.profiles.active:local}")
private String activeProfile;

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    if (activeProfile.equalsIgnoreCase("aws")) {
        Config config = new Config();
        GroupConfig groupConfig = new GroupConfig();
        groupConfig.setName("ec2-group");
        groupConfig.setPassword("ec2-password");
        config.setGroupConfig(groupConfig);

        JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);

        AwsConfig awsConfig = joinConfig.getAwsConfig();
        awsConfig.setEnabled(true);
        awsConfig.setSecurityGroupName("poc-hzcast-sg");
        awsConfig.setIamRole("my_ec2-poc-hz-role");
        awsConfig.setRegion("us-east-1");

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
}
```

Command used to run this:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=aws hazelcast-aws-poc.jar
```

Here is stackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oneController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oneService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hzPocUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hzPocUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hazelcastInstance'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/hzpoc/poc/awshazelcast/components/HzPocConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.hzpoc.poc.awshazelcast.AwsHazelcastApplication.main(AwsHazelcastApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [aws-hazelcast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [aws-hazelcast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [aws-hazelcast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [aws-hazelcast-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oneService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hzPocUtils'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hzPocUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hazelcastInstance'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/hzpoc/poc/awshazelcast/components/HzPocConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hzPocUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hazelcastInstance'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/hzpoc/poc/awshazelcast/components/HzPocConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [com/hzpoc/poc/awshazelcast/components/HzPocConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:136) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:195) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:174) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:124) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58) ~[hazelcast-3.9.4.jar!/:3.9.4]
at com.hzpoc.poc.awshazelcast.components.HzPocConfig.hazelcastInstance(HzPocConfig.java:35) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.hzpoc.poc.awshazelcast.components.HzPocConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48c84597.CGLIB$hazelcastInstance$0() ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.hzpoc.poc.awshazelcast.components.HzPocConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48c84597$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$51b3fe53.invoke() ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at com.hzpoc.poc.awshazelcast.components.HzPocConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48c84597.hazelcastInstance() ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

I am using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/configure-hazelcast-withnbspec2) reference.

Comment: why don't you enable debug level logging? here https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.9.4/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/instance/HazelcastInstanceImpl.java#L136 says node was not started after attempt to start.

Comment: tried starting the server in debug mode as well, but the same errors. Adding a lot of logger lines, figured out, it is reading and processing all the configurations perfectly fine. The error is only at Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()

Comment: Don't hesitate to share it via pastebin or other service, we love detailed logs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this was due to mismatch in hazelcast dependencies. `hazelcast-aws` 2.3 is not compatible with `hazelcast-core` version 3.10

Two options here: 
1. Use compatible versions:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
      <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.6</version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Use hazelcast-all which internally will bring hazelcast-aws dependency.

Refer [hazelcast-aws github](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws) repo and [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/13968).

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes cluster environment, I figured out for an issue in embedded hazelcast which is because of version mismatch. So you must align your hazelcast version dependency in pom.xml or etc. If you only need to use hazelcast for current application then you just change cluster-name in hazelcast.yaml.

```
hazelcast:
 #not able join dev which is current running by other
 #application with different hazelcast version so change cluster-name from dev to dev-ptt to fix this issue
 #caused by: java.lang.illegalstateexception: node failed to start! in hazelcast embedded
 cluster-name: dev-ptt
  group:
    network:
      join:
       multicast:
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is another instance of your app running on `localhost:5701`, this would also cause this error.

In this case, in addition to the given workarounds, you might try to use another port instead of `5701` for your app.